# It is possible to override timeout value more than 2 min while making rest call with httpclient from @angular/common/http in angular

Tags: angular, tomcat

I have a requirement where in processing time for server is proportional to the file uploaded from the UI.
Application is able to fetch data from server if processing is less than 2 min . But for most of the cases the server processing time is **more than 2 min**.

I have tried using proxy configuration as below in my local which is working fine.But during when the application is deployed in tomcat server.Every request is aborted after 2 min with empty error response.

```
  "/api":
  {
    "target":"http://localhost:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "timeout": 360000
  }
}
```

So Is there any way to override timeout value to make the connection alive until the server process the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about a [local proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) as some Tomcat server *somewhere*, therefor the change you want should be done on the **real** server:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

take a look at different options related to timeouts: `connectionTimeout`, `disableUploadTimeout` and adjust setting to the desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will try that option.But I just wanted to know if there is any way from the client side (in Angular 8 ) to increase the connection time, because when I tried hitting the GET api call(one of my backend api calls) which takes around 3-5 min in chrome browser I was able to fetch the details.

Comment: If server doesn't support it you cannot increase connection timeout from browser. Also, was looking for the answer and didn't find such - only words with correlates with my answer. There is something with Proxies(not Angular's, but a real, intermediate one) and `Connection: keep-alive` header, but I am not sure how to work with it without trying myself, sorry.